# Klein's Calculus: An Intuitive and Physical Approach-basic algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am following an example that involves finding the rate of change for a function $y=x^3-5$ for $\sqrt[3]{5}$. The example gets to a stage where

$-\frac{x_1}{3}+\frac{5}{3x_1^2}+x_1=x_2$

The example then factors out 1/3 from the equation and gets

$1/3(2x_1+\frac{5}{x_1^2})=x_2$

What has happened to the negative sign? I thought the result would lead you to

$1/3(-\frac{2x_1}{3}+\frac{5}{x_1^2})$

However when I use my method to find the rate of change I don't get the correct result. I would like to know why the negative sign appears to disappear when the author factors out 1/3 from the equation?

Comment: $-\frac{x_1}{3} +x_1 = \frac{2x_1}{3}$

Comment: Wouldn't factoring out 1/3 of the equation lead to $\frac{x_1}{3}-x_1=-\frac{2x_1}{3}$?

Comment: $-\frac{x_1}{3} +x_1 +\frac{5}{3x_1^2} = \frac{1}{3} \left(-x_1 +3x_1 + \frac {5}{x_1^2} \right ) =  \frac{1}{3} \left(2x_1 + \frac {5}{x_1^2} \right )$

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand now. When you are factoring out the term you have to multiply $x_1$ by 3 to make sure the equation stays the same.